# I'm trying to make a discord bot receive this error [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Following is the code snippet I am trying:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents:["GUILD_VOICE_STATES","VOICE_STATE_UPDATE"]});
const config = require("./config.json");

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

To enable your intents,

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });
```

You will also have to require the Intents class,

```js
const { Discord, Intents } = require("discord.js");
```

Most importantly however, `"VOICE_STATE_UPDATE"` is not an intent, its an event that can only be received with the `GUILD_VOICE_STATE` intent

Answer (score 1):

`VOICE_STATE_UPDATE` is not a valid intent. The `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` is what you want (you have this but `VOICE_STATE_UPDATE` is invalid). These are the intents you should have to track voice states:

- GuildMember intents
- Voice states

Therefore this is how you should declare `client`

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    "GUILD_VOICE_STATES",
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MEMBERS"
  ]
})
//GUILDS is required for some other intents like messages and members
```